# Comparison of using Alfresco and Jackrabbit CMS on Liferay portal

Tags: java, content-management-system, alfresco, jackrabbit, liferay-6

I'd like to know your thoughts about using these two CMS on Liferay. I know, that jackrabbit is rather a framework and reference JCR implementation. I'm more interested in the situation, when you have Liferay portlet and you need a CMS repository other then the liferay Document Library, because you need more features.

What I am concerned about:

- Level of Metadata Extraction from various document formats ( I see that both are using Apache tika parsers)
- Level of Content Transformation - for instance dealing with not quite valid PDFs (OCR)
- How easily can developer extend functionality (for instance implementing various actions on document processing)

It takes a lot of time to try both of them, I have to decide on one and stick with it.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never did anything serious with Jackrabbit, but did quite a lot of projects with Alfresco.

Since there's an ongoing [joint effort](http://www.alfresco.com/products/integrations/liferay/) between Alfresco and Liferay in order to provide a solid and validated integration, Alfresco should at least minimize the integration efforts between the two applications, and possibly have a good starting point for your project.

From the functional point of view, the following apply to Alfresco:

- as you noted, Alfresco makes use of Tika for metadata extraction. By default a number of document types [are supported](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Metadata_Extraction#Default_Extractors), and adding your own custom metadata extractor is quite easy and well documented.
- Alfresco [will make use of Tika](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Content_Transformation_and_Metadata_Extraction_with_Apache_Tika) for transformations when [project Swift](http://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF/fixforversion/10653) (an upcoming version) will be released. As per now, tools like pdfbox and OpenOffice are sitting behind [content transformations](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Content_Transformations), which provide good reliability for the average case.
- offering extension points for the repository is something Alfresco is quite good at: you can hook you code upon [events on specific content types](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Services_Framework#Component_Policies), configure [rules](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Actions_and_Rules) on folders that get triggered upon creation/update/delete of their inner content and so on